# how to specify an app to migrate to a schema django

Tags: postgresql, python-3.5, django-migrations, django-1.8, django-postgresql

I recently did an inspectdb of our old database which is on MySQL. We want to move to postgre. now we want the inspection to migrate to a different schema is there a migrate command to achieve this? so different apps shall use different schemas in the same database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so simple!

python manage.py migrate "app_name"